# How to connect ViewController to class in Xamarin

Tags: facebook, xamarin.ios, viewcontroller

I have created the ViewController manually within Xamarin iOS as well as the class it is associated with. My app can launch but immeditely terminates as it appears the class is not linked to the ViewController.

How can I connect them?

Comment: When you said "created the ViewController manually" you mean a XIB file?

Comment: @apineda I think the issue likes with the Xamarin Facebook iOS SDK. Do you have experience?

Comment: @apineda I can get this app to run on its' own, but when I try to add components to my app, the issue above appears. https://github.com/MattHarrington/FacebookiOSSample

Comment: What component are you trying to use? the Xamarin IOS Facebook SDK? did you follow every step? specially the ones that has to be with the info.plist file. Also is good idea to visit the Facebook developer portal and check the IOS documentation (in your case) in case they have changed anything.

Comment: Yes, followed all instructions several times. Have you ever integrated Facebook? The odd thing is the app example I posted works,  but when I try to recreate, the app can build but simply flashes on screen and goes back to my home phones main screen.

Comment: Yeah I have integrated that library, not that specific version but yeah. Your problem really sounds like something missing in the info.plist. As told before go to developer.facebook and check for their steps-by-step guide and compare.

Comment: Your question is unclear. It does not mention facebook SDK. Please update your question with all relevant information and code. Also "created the ViewController manually" is very unclear. It can mean a number of things.